# Matlab: avoid for loops to find the maximum among values with same labels

Tags: matlab, for-loop, label

I need to find the maximum among values with same labels, in matlab, and I am trying to avoid using for loops.

Specifically, I have an array `L` of labels and an array `V` of values, same size. I need to produce an array `S` which contains, for each value of `L`, the maximum value of `V`. An example will explain better:

```
L = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,2,3,4]

V = [5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6]
```

Then, the values of the output array S will be:

```
s(1) = 9 (the values V(i) such that L(i) == 1 are: 5,4,3,9 -> max = 9)

s(2) = 8 (the values V(i) such that L(i) == 2 are: 2,1,2,8 -> max = 8)

s(3) = 7 (the values V(i) such that L(i) == 3 are: 3,4,5,7 -> max = 7)

s(4) = 8 (the values V(i) such that L(i) == 4 are: 6,7,8,6 -> max = 8)
```

this can be trivially implemented by traversing the arrays `L` and `V` with a for loop, but in Matlab for loops are slow, so I was looking for a faster solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a standard job for [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

Three cases need to be considered, with increasing generality:

- Integer labels.
- Integer labels, specify fill value.
- Remove gaps; or non-integer labels. General case.

### Integer labels

You can just use

```
S = accumarray(L(:), V(:), [], @max).';
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> L = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 2 3 7];
>> V = [5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6];
>> S = accumarray(L(:), V(:), [], @max).'
S =
     9     8     7     8
```

### Integer labels, specify fill value

If there are **gaps between integers** in `L`, the above will give a `0` result for the non-existing labels. If you want to change that **fill value** (for example to `NaN`), use a fifth input argument in `acccumarray`:

```
S = accumarray(L(:), V(:), [], @max, NaN).';
```

Example:

```
>> L = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 2 3 7]; %// last element changed
>> V = [5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6]; %// same as in your example
>> S = accumarray(L(:), V(:), [], @max, NaN).'
S =
     9     8     7     8   NaN   NaN     6
```

### Remove gaps; or non-integer labels. General case

When the gaps between integer labels are large, using a fill value may be inefficient. In that case you may want to get only the meaningful values in `S`, without fill values, i.e.**skip non-existing labels**. Also, it may be the case that `L` **doesn't necessarily contain integers**.

These two issues are solved by applying [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to the labels before using `accumarray`:

```
[~, ~, Li] = unique(L); %// transform L into consecutive integers
S = accumarray(Li(:), V(:), [], @max, NaN).';
```

Example:

```
>> L = [1.5 1.5 1.5 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 2 3 7.8]; %// note: non-integer values
>> V = [5   4   3   2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6  ]; %// same as in your example
>> [~, ~, Li] = unique(L); %// transform L into consecutive integers
>> S = accumarray(Li(:), V(:), [], @max, NaN).'
S =
     9     5     8     7     8     6
```

Comment: Hmm it is quite frustrating, so often I work out a solution just to find you to have posted a faster one-liner solution :(...  The only thing is that your solution doesn't work if there is a zero as value in `L` (no problem if its in `V`).

Comment: or if there is a negative or non integer value in `L`

Comment: @TheMinion of course it won't. The first input to `accumarray` is an array of subscripts. Having 0, negative, or non-integer subscripts in MATLAB is meaningless.

Comment: @excaza Yes but in the OP `L` is an array of labels which do not have to be positive integers only. It could be in another case as the example posted by OP an array of strings, or floating datapoints, that is why I posted my comment(s), that the solution from Luis is good but only for positive integer values in `L`

Comment: @TheMinion Sorry to be frustrating :-) I have updated my solution to cover the general case. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: For the last case ("Remove gaps; or non-integer labels. General case"), the first output of `unique` is helpful. It contains the corresponding labels for the result `S`

Answer (score 4):

```
helper=[L.', V.'];
helper=sortrows(helper,-2);
[~,idx,~]=unique(helper(:,1));
S=helper(idx,2);
```

What I do is: I join the two arrays as columns. Then I sort them regarding second column with biggest element first. Then I get the idx of the unique Values in `L` before I return the corresponding Values from `V`.

The solution from **Luis Mendo** is faster. But as far as I see his solution doesn't work if there is a zero,negative value or a noninteger inside `L`:

```
Luis solution: Elapsed time is 0.722189 seconds.
My solution: Elapsed time is 2.575943 seconds.
```

I used:

```
L= ceil(rand(1,500)*10);
V= ceil(rand(1,500)*250);
```

and ran the code 10000 times.

Comment: +1 for the generality of the approach and for the benchmarking